# nested functions: Arrange() and desc()

Tags: r, dplyr

With gapminder being a tibble and lifeExp being a variable name in gapminder, I tried using two functions arrange() and desc().

This works:

```
gapminder %>% arrange(desc(lifeExp))
```

This does not work:

```
gapminder %>% desc(arrange(lifeExp)
```

> Error: unused argument (arrange(lifeExp))

I am not sure why, any help with be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new on this, but it seems that the grammar is different in each line of code.

gapminder %>% arrange(desc(lifeExp)) # is read like "the tibble gapminder", "then" "arrange" it "in descendant values" of "lifeExp"

gapminder %>% desc(arrange(lifeExp) # is read like "the tibble gapminder", "then" "in descendant order" "arrange it" by "lifeExp". The arrange command is for a tibble, while a desc is for aiming at one variable.

Espero me haya hecho entender bro

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is more or less right but the reason for this is due to the nature of the piping operator %>%.

The pipe takes whatever is to the left and passes it *as the first argument* to the function on the right. If you look at the documentation for `dplyr::desc` you can see it only takes a single argument x (the vector to be arranged), so your second example is equivalent to

```
desc(gapminder, arrange(lifeExp))
```

and R is seeing two arguments where it expects one (hence the error message).

`arrange()` on the other hand accepts two arguments, so your first example which is equivalent to:

```
arrange(gapminder, desc(lifeExp))
```

works, as R is expecting two arguments to `arrange()` and that is what it sees.